# NSDictionary always shows null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am having problem initializing nsdictionary and adding it to array. I tried two appoaches but failed in both. My dictionary is always null.

Appoach1:

```
NSMutableDictionary *Data =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"State_Name",@"2",@"Name",@"3",@"Address",@"4",@"Ph", nil];// initialized in viewdidload


-(void)find:(NSInteger)Item{


        switch (Item) {
        case 0:

            [Data setValue:string forKey:@"State_Name"];
            break;
        case 1:
            [Data setValue:string forKey:@"Name"];
            break;
        case 2:
            [Data setValue:string forKey:@"TAddress"];
            break;
        case 3:
            [Data setValue:string forKey:@"Ph"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }         
}
```

Approach2:

```
NSMutableDictionary *Data =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:str1,@"State_Name",str2,@"Name",str3,@"Address",str4,@"Ph", nil];
```

Could any one tell whats wrong with this code. Am I using nsdictionary's in a wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: could you port the entire viewDidLoad code?

Comment: You need to post more code, including the actual code that doesn't work, and where you are seeing the problem (i.e., what you think is NULL, and why you think that).

Comment: @din Gypsa is right the scope of your dictionary is limited to viewDidLoad. You need to declare the an instance var in your header file to access throughout the class.

Comment: I have a global mutablearray declared in .h and I want add a dictionary declared locally and keep adding the dictionay again and again(array of dictionarys). I dont have any code related to dictionary in viewdidload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks correct. My guess is `string` is nil. `setValue:forKey:` allows nil (in turn removes existing object).
try `setObject:forKey:` , it will raise exception if value(string) is nil or check if string is nil ...

Answer (score 2):

I executed your code
What change you have to do is:-
in your .h file write:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *Data;
```

in your .m file write:-

```
Data =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"State_Name",@"2",@"Name",@"3",@"Address",@"4",@"Ph", nil];// initialized in viewdidload
```

Comment: I declared nsdictionary in .m immediately after synthesize. can't we do that way?

Comment: I just tried to put the some random values and then replace with the actual values in switch case.

Answer (score 0):

To your first approach:
What exactly is spposed to be your key and what your value in the initialiser?
It seems to me you mixed up the order.

Besides that : you put strings into the dictionary but refere to a nsinteger in your switch. Are you doing a conversion somewhere in between ?

Comment: adding to the point above, I think you should store NSInteger as the object stored

Comment: I just tried to put the some random values and then replace with the actual values in switch case.